# Adjusted Rand index - more clusters than categories in response variable

Tags: clustering

I ran clustering analysis for different k values - different numbers of clusters in R. Now I want to evaluate success with Adjusted Rand Index. However, my response variable has only 2 categories. So for 2 categories this is straightforward, in ideal case I would have all data points with one response value in one cluster and all data points with second response value in second cluster. But for multiple clusters I am not sure if I can use this method. I am using R and this command:

```
adjustedRandIndex(km.out$cluster, Quality)
```

Comment: You might want to clarify this question a bit.
So you have $n$ values that you group into $k$ clusters? based on what?
Once this is clarified then if you have a $k \times m$ contingency table then the rand index, or it's adjusted variant is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Cluster evaluation indexes like Rand index are *designed* for comparing results with different number of cases.

Clustering is just something very different than classification... that is why you have quite different measures. But you should **study what the measure evaluates** - it may not be what you are interested in, and you may need to choose the most appropriate measure for your task instead.

Rand for example is symmetric, but in your case you may be better off with measuring a weighted cluster purity instead.